How to Ignore Permissions Error with Apps Script on Google Sheets
I have an Apps Script that updates columns in a Google Sheet. It is only updating unprotected columns. At the end I do a sort on all columns (including some protected columns). Those without permissions get an error from google sheets.
I tried to put a try/catch statement on the sort but that did not work. Google sheets still gives the permissions error and the code stops.
Can I either put some form of a try/catch around the sort or can I somehow see if the user has permissions before the code executes?
Here is the code that gives the Google Sheets permission error:
var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
var ss = wb.getSheetByName(sheetname)
var sortrange = ss.getRange('A5:AM')
sortrange.sort(1)

This is the try/catch I attempted:
var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
var ss = wb.getSheetByName(sheetname)
var sortrange = ss.getRange('A5:AM')
try {
  sortrange.sort(1)
}
catch(ExceptionError) {
}



catch(Exception e) {} is not valid javascript for a start

Please add a [mcve]. This should include the textual error message.

You need to put the api request in the try...catch.... Besides, there would be a syntax error of Exception e.
try {
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  var ss = wb.getSheetByName(sheetname)
  var sortrange = ss.getRange('A5:AM')
  sortrange.sort(1)
}
catch(ExceptionError) {
 // do nothing since you want to ignore it.
}


This still causes the Google Sheets permissions error. It doesn't seem to be treated as a Java error, just a Google Sheets error. Thanks for the heads up on the syntax, it could never get far enough to see the exception.

You can modify protected ranges through Protection Class.

In Google's Documentation, you can find helpful information and examples that can clarify possible doubts about usage;
I suggest you the following strategy: you'll  have to allow editing before you do the sorting, then eventually protect the range once more; of course, you could come up with different ways;
By storing the returning value of the function shown below, you'll be able to iterate over it and remove protection -- check canEdit() in the documentation -- of the range stopping your routine;

SpreadsheetApp   
 .getActive()
 .getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);


Another strategy could be raising privillege to the Editor(s), and setting yourself as one -- check the method addEditor(user) in the documentation to do so;


Thank you for the response. I did read over that before. I didn't think that would work. I thought the Script was run as the user so I assumed they couldn't edit the protections. So was I wrong and any user can edit protections if done through App Script?

@Stalwart385 Apparently, all users allowed to Edit a sheet are also allowed to acess its bound script and edit it.

A simpler solution was to use Python and the gspread module. That way it is treated as a single user that I can give full permissions to. Events to trigger the code may be tricky in some cases but it works perfectly in mine.
